# How can be set the network Bandwidth while load testing of any application using jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I am doing the load testing of our API using jmeter. Now I need to set the network bandwidth to 256kbps and 512kbps.

I added below lines in apache-jmeter/bin/jmeter.properties but that didn't works.

```
#httpclient.socket.http.cps=32728
#httpclient.socket.https.cps=32728
```

is any other approach to set the network bandwidth or any other best tool for this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to remove this `#` character as it indicates a [comment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file#Comments_2) therefore JMeter ignores this line
2. It's [better to make configuration changes in *user.properties* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter), this way you will get confidence that your setup will survive upgrade to the most recent JMeter version

More information: [How to Simulate Different Network Speeds in Your JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-simulate-different-network-speeds-your-jmeter-load-test)